# Expected value 2 distributions

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expected-value

There are 2 continuous normal distributions  $(1,^2)$ and $(-1,^2)$. There is a variable $x$, with probability $p_1$ it is sampled from the first distribution and probability $p_{-1}$ from the second. I have a signal that tells me that $x$ is higher (or lower) than some constant $y$.

I want to calculate the expected value of $x$. How can I do this?

Comment: $y$ is a variable or constant?  What do you know about $y$?

Comment: The distributions $N(\cdot,\cdot)$ are normal?  They have the same standard deviation or variance?

Comment: I just edited the question, y is a constant, and yes, normal distributions with the same variance.

Comment: From which distribution are you sampling $X$? Are you sampling from either $N(-1,\sigma^2)$ or $N(1,\sigma^2)$ with a certain probability?

Comment: I have edited the question, originally it was 0.5 but it could actually help me if it is in terms of probabilities.

Comment: So you don't know which distribution from which you're sampling, but you know whether $X\geq y$ or $X<y$? I'm going through some calculations and I doubt you're going to get a closed form for this, unless you're okay with the error function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $S_{-1},S_1$ be the events that you sampled from
$N(-1,\sigma^2),N(1,\sigma^2)$. Suppose your signal indicates that $X\geq y$. You need to calculate $\mathbb{E}(X|X\geq y)$. We get from the total law of expectation that $$\mathbb{E}(X|X\geq y)=\mathbb{E}(X|X\geq y,S_{-1})P(S_{-1}|X\geq y)+\mathbb{E}(X|X\geq y,S_{1})P(S_{1}|X\geq y)$$ First observe how $$\mathbb{E}(X|X\geq y,S_{-1})=\frac{\int_y^{\infty}\frac{x}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\big(\frac{x+1}{\sigma}\big)^2}dx}{\int_y^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\big(\frac{x+1}{\sigma}\big)^2}dx}$$ $$\mathbb{E}(X|X\geq y,S_{1})=\frac{\int_y^{\infty}\frac{x}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\big(\frac{x-1}{\sigma}\big)^2}dx}{\int_y^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\big(\frac{x-1}{\sigma}\big)^2}dx}$$ It is not reasonable to assume that $S_{-1}$ and $\{X\geq y\}$ are independent; knowing, for example, that $X\geq 2$ would make it more likely that we sampled from $N(1,\sigma^2)$ than from $N(-1,\sigma^2)$. We can calculate our "updated" probability $P(S_{-1}|X\geq y)$ via Baye's Theorem: $$P(S_{-1}|X\geq y)=\frac{P(X \geq y|S_{-1})p_{-1}}{P(X \geq y|S_{-1})p_{-1}+P(X \geq y|S_{1})p_{1}}$$ This becomes $$P(S_{-1}|X\geq y)=\frac{p_{-1}\int_y^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\big(\frac{x+1}{\sigma}\big)^2}dx}{p_{-1}\int_y^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\big(\frac{x+1}{\sigma}\big)^2}dx+p_{1}\int_y^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\big(\frac{x-1}{\sigma}\big)^2}dx}$$ Similarly, $$P(S_{1}|X\geq y)=\frac{p_{1}\int_y^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\big(\frac{x-1}{\sigma}\big)^2}dx}{p_{-1}\int_y^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\big(\frac{x+1}{\sigma}\big)^2}dx+p_{1}\int_y^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\big(\frac{x-1}{\sigma}\big)^2}dx}$$ Combining all four components will give you an expression for $\mathbb{E}(X|X\geq y)$. On the other hand, if your signal indicates that $X<y$, you should be able to replace every $\int_y^{\infty}$ with $\int_{-\infty}^y$ and get an expression for $\mathbb{E}(X|X<y)$.

I hope this helps.